# Does exception handling work if the throw block and landing pad are in diffrent section?

Tags: c++, exception, stack, stack-unwinding, uncaughtexceptionhandler

Consider below case, Which ends up crashing with unwinder complaining
_URC_END_OF_STACK and no handler found in _UA_SEARCH_PHASE

```
class array{
public: 
 int foo() {
      throw 5;
  }
};

int main() {
  array a0;
  try {
    a0.foo();  
  }
  catch(const int )
  {}
}
```

For above case my linker puts foo in .text._ZN5array3fooEv section and everything else in .text section? which is not case with llvm ld.lld(all in .text).

Comment: This looks innocent to me. It does run properly on [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e4183f9eb178a29) (as I expected). You should [edit] in which compiler you are using in which OS.

Comment: And that's all in the same source file? Depending on kind of exception handling exceptions do not cross dynamic library borders (sjlj shouldn't, seh does, if I recall correctly) – but within the same source or even library/executable this all should be fine; that's all what's exception handling about anyway! Maybe, though, you missed some compiler flag e.g. required to explicitly enable exception handling (and the right kind of)?

Comment: Nothing about sections in the standard. And [the standard library throws](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) stuff with no warning about similar limitations, so yours seems like a bug.

Comment: To me, that kind of error message suggests an internal compiler bug.

Comment: @molbdnilo   Or a problem with how the program is built and executed (about which there is no information given).   For example, if  `A::foo()` is in a DLL, there can be problems of exceptions crossing the DLL boundary (depending on how the DLL is built, how the program links to it at run time, etc etc).

Comment: Either way, [it's not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/sPhv8aGhq). Please provide a [mre], possibly including how you build your program and what compiler you're using.

Comment: Yes It's a partial linked Object.., And i found a workaround for this issue..
For now giving --force-group-allocation to GNU LD, And putting (.text.*) in linker script for combining them all in .text works..
I Do not understand why just having (.text.*) does not work?? Why also need to give flag --force-group-allocation...
LLVM-LLD works with (.text.*) in linker script..

Comment: "Does exception handling work if the throw block and landing pad are in diffrent section?" - Yes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

main -> .text
foo  -> .text._ZN5array3fooEv (linker not merging them)

Answer depends on your unwind library, for this case mylibUnwind.a checks for bounds of .text and foo not being in .text results in _URC_END_OF_STACK.

Comment: This is all in the same translation unit. No unwind library or linker is involved here.

Comment: I would suggest you to read some topics like.. 1) How loader process relocatable file. 2) How different OS modify libunwind acording to their criteria.. etc.